# Mongoose virtual fields included in toJSON by default: schemaOptions.toJSON.virtuals = true; still doesn't include virtual fields by default

Tags: virtual, mongoose

I saw in another answer that in order to include the virtual fields you must do like https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongoose-orm/HjrPAP_WXYs

```
var schemaOptions = {
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
  }
};
```

which I've done;

Now in the Schema:

```
 new Schema({...}, schemaOptions);
```

But still so, the data doesn't include the virtual.. :s

But like this works:

```
var docsCallback = function(err, docs){
    var i = docs.length;
    var nDocs = [];
    while(i--){
        nDocs[i] = docs[i].toObject({virtuals: true});
    }
    done(nDocs);
}
```

Comment: Does toObject automatically `.populate` any `refs` found in the Object? Let's say a `Post` object that has a `User` ref in it. @Totty.js

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Just tried:

```
  var schemaOptions = {
    toObject: {
      virtuals: true
    }
  };
```

and worked! ;)

Now by default I use:

```
  var schemaOptions = {
    toObject: {
      virtuals: true
    }
    ,toJSON: {
      virtuals: true
    }
  };
```

Comment: just accept your own answer so the question shows as answered in the question list

Answer (score 13):

You can do this way as well:

```
docs.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked only after adding `getters: true` to schema options, as mentioned in [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject), i.e.

```
var schemaOptions = {
  toObject: {
    getters: true
  },
  toJSON: {
    getters: true
  }
};
```