# After upgrade to MongoDB 3.0 App crashing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, npm

Not really sure what's going wrong (inherited this code, didn't write it) but here goes.

I tried to update my MongoDB to 3.0 (as Heroku, which is hosting the app/DB is deprecating support for 2.6, which is what it was on).

After I did this, my node app started crashing immediately. After some digging I figured out I needed to update my mongoose version.

Now, the server is working but the iPhone app talking to the server is getting status 304's when it starts up. I'm guessing that there's still some connectivity issue between the app/node server and MongoDB.

The logs are fairly useless - just a lot of "dropping [object]" stuff I imagine is coming from not being able to connect.

Any help at all would be appreciated. I would roll back my DB to a backup I made of the 2.6 version but Heroku doesn't support in-place database creation from backups...

EDIT: The problem had to do with the way null-fields were set in the JSON output from the server after the mongoose upgrade.

Anyone having this issue might want to look at: [Mongoose virtual fields included in toJSON by default: schemaOptions.toJSON.virtuals = true; still doesn't include virtual fields by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557804/mongoose-virtual-fields-included-in-tojson-by-default-schemaoptions-tojson-virt)

Comment: Is it cached in iPhone? Can you try by clearing cache once.

Comment: Can you provide the code and output for a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?